Strong activation of MAPK signaling pathway
I am reading a paper named "Mathematical models of protein kinase signal transduction". In that paper, I encountered a condition called "strongly activated pathways".
In that section, I need to calculate signal duration time for the strongly activated pathway. For strongly activated pathway, concentration of phosphorylated kinase at step $i$ is
$X_{i} = \frac{X_{i}^{max}R(t)}{K_{Mj}+R(t)}$,
where $K_{Mj}$ and $X_{i}^{max}$ are constants. $K_{Mj}$ is effective Michaelis constant of receptor, and $X_{i}^{max}$ is the maximum concentration. Here, $R(t)=Re^{-\lambda t}$
In the paper, it says signal duration $\sigma$ can be calculated as
$\sigma=\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln{\left(2+\frac{R}{K_{Mj}}\right)}$.
In the paper, $\sigma$ is defined as
$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{Q}{I} - \tau^{2}}$,
where $I = \int_{0}^{\infty}X_{i}dt$, $\tau=T/I$, where $T=\int_{0}^{\infty}{tX_{i}dt}$,  and $Q = \int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{2}X_{i}dt}$.
I first calculated $I$ and I got
$I = \frac{x_{i}^{max}}{\lambda}\ln{\left(1+\frac{R}{K_{Mj}}\right)}$.
In addition, I proceed to calculate $T=\int_{0}^{\infty}{tX_{i}}dt$, but I cannot find solution. The same goes for $Q$. Thus, I couldn't get the result of $\sigma$ as shown in the paper.
Is my approach wrong? or Am I lost at some point?

You might have more luck over at Mathematics SE. Personally, I don't know how to solve those integrals, but the folks over there probably will.
